# java.sql.SQLException: SQL logic error or missing database, SQLite, JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have created a database connection with SQLite using JDBC in Java. My SQL statements execute properly, but sometimes I get the following error while I use `conn.commit()`:

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQL logic error or missing database
```

Can anyone please help me how to avoid this type of problem. Is there a better approach of calling JDBC programs?

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/Data/database.db3");
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

String query = "Update Chits set BlockedForChit = 0 where ServerChitID = '" + serverChitId + "' AND ChitGatewayID = '" + chitGatewayId + "'";
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        try {
            stmt.execute(query);
            conn.commit();
            stmt.close();
            stmt = null;
        }
```

Comment: If stmt is null, how are you calling .execute on it?

Comment: how did you solve this problem? getting the same error on calling commit().... :(

Comment: make sure you add the conn to every class/method that uses it , that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Can your variables serverChitId & chitGatewayId contain characters that would corrupt the SQL? It is usually safer to use PreparedStatements:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Update Chits set BlockedForChit = 0 where ServerChitID = ? AND ChitGatewayID = ?");
ps.setString(1, serverChitId);
ps.setString(2, chitGatewayId);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

This way the JDBC driver is responsible for making sure the necessary escapes are made to the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `conn.setAutoCommit` to true. Also you need to delete `conn.commit();`.
If you are doing this inside of a function, make your function synchronized.
It's even more better if you use PreparedStatement instead of Statement.
All this is happening because sometimes you are trying to connect and modify your database at a same time and since the last connection hasn't commited yet, it throws that exception. When you set it to autoCommit it will handle the flow by itself.(it was really painful for me cause it says nothing more, I read all of the org.sqlite.DB files to find this out)

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/Data/database.db3");
conn.setAutoCommit(true);

PreparedStatement ps = "Update Chits set BlockedForChit = 0 where ServerChitID = ? AND ChitGatewayID = ? ";
        ps.setString(1, serverChitId); 
        ps.setString(2, chitGatewayId);

        try {
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
```